# Event log errors with Forefront Identity Manager / User Profile Service

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, forefront

My event log is filled with errors with event ID 3. I am running a SharePoint 2010 farm with one front-end server and a dedicated database server.

The events look something like this:

```
Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Service: System.Data.DataException: This request has an invalid target: A202675A-DBE1-40F5-8844-2E620195ECA1. The invalid target identifier is FB89AEFA-5EA1-47F1-8890-ABE7797D6497.
at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DataAccess.DoRequestCreation(RequestType request, Guid cause, Boolean doEvaluation)
at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Data.DataAccess.CreateRequest(RequestType request, Guid cause, Boolean doEvaluation)
at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.RequestDispatcher.CreateRequest(UniqueIdentifier requestor, UniqueIdentifier targetIdentifier, OperationType operation, String businessJustification, List`1 requestParameters, CultureInfo locale, Boolean isChildRequest, Guid cause, Boolean doEvaluation)
at Microsoft.ResourceManagement.WebServices.ResourceManagementService.Put(Message request)
```

There is a post from another guy with the same error on the MS forums here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepoint2010setup/thread/2bd3b32d-b56d-4a87-b29f-e3f2784a3b12

The errors correspond with the timer job `User Profile Service Application - System Job to Manage user Profile Synchronization`, which runs every minute. Despite descriptions, I tried extending the running time to every 5 minutes instead and the error now appears every 5th minute instead of every minute.

Some background:
I have had issues with the User Profile Service and had to restart it a couple of times. However, I don't know what the cause of this is. I fear that the `target identifier` is pointing at a wrong / old GUID for a User Profile Service Application, but is there any way to change this?

Has anyone had similar problems and have an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to recreate the UPA. See this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2432041

Also, what CU are you on?